# python scripts configured by pyproject.toml are not executable on MacOS

Tags: python, setup.py, pyproject.toml

I have a python scripts package. Recently I changed setup.py to pyproject.toml to get rid of the alert from pip.

However, the installed scripts built by pyproject.toml work well on Windows platform, but NOT on Mac OS, which shows that they have no executable permission ('-rw-r--r--'). While this was fine when I use setup.py ('-rwxr-xr-x').

I have tried three ways below and I prefer the first one as they are easy enough and I don't need executable files but just python to run them in the terminal.

```
[options]
scripts=[]
```

```
[tool.setuptools]
script-files=[]
```

```
[project.scripts]
...
```

All of them give the same permission so I guess this is a difference between setup.py and pyproject.toml.

Could anyone tell me how to make them executable and why this happens? Thanks a mill!

ps. Please don't tell me to use chmod. there are many work stations using them so I can't change one by one. Thanks!

Comment: The first way now looks like being deprecated. Using second one atm. But the scripts are still unexecutable on Mac.

Comment: I recommend you provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have found an answer.
Previously, I was using the Windows platform to build and upload my package.
This time, I used Mac OS to build and upload my package. And the terminal is able to run the scripts now. I've tried several Mac and Windows work stations and all work fine.

But still, I don't know if this is because the permission of the files are different from platforms or something else.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).